# Rails - Eager load 2 tables, but filter one - Fixing N+1

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :destinations, :through => :trips
  has_many :destination_reviews

class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :trips
  has_many :destination_reviews

class DestinationReview < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :destination
```

Different users can leave reviews for the same destination.

We're building a table that shows all destinations belonging to a user. The user has left reviews for some (but not all) of those destinations.

**Controller:**

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
@user_reviews = @user.destination_reviews
```

**View:**

```
<% @user.destinations.each do |destination| %>
  <% review = @user_reviews.find_by_destination_id(dest.id) %>
  <% if review %>
    <div class="review>
      ...show the review
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="add-review>
      ...prompt user to add a review
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The N+1 is happening at `@user_reviews.find_by_destination_id(dest.id)`, where @user_reviews is a preloaded list of the user's reviews.

How can I eager load all destinations belonging to this user, including any reviews the user has left for these destinations?

I'm looking for some query like:

```
dest_ids = current_user.destinations.pluck(:id)`
Destination.includes(:destination_reviews).where(id: dest_ids).where('destination_reviews.user_id = ?', user_id)
```

But that throws the error:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "destination_reviews"`

Alternatively, if there was a way I could write `@user_reviews.find_by_destination_id(dest.id)` without having it re-query the database, that would work.

Please let me know if that is clear or if I should add more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `group_by`:

```
@user_reviews = @user.desintation_reviews.group_by(&:destination_id)
```

then in the view

```
<% review = @user_reviews[dest.id] %>
```

That gives you one query to get the user's destinations, and another to get their reviews.

Or you could get it down to a single query with some joins plus using `select` to create some pseudo-attributes on the `Destination`, and then you can just pull everything you want from `dest`. It's going to be more complicated though, especially since you're going through a join table. It's going to be something like this (not tested):

```
current_user.destinations.
             joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN destination_reviews r " +
                   "ON r.user_id = trips.user_id " +
                   "AND r.destination_id = destinations.id").
             select("destinations.*, r.foo AS review_foo, r.bar AS review_bar")
```

and then this:

```
<% if destination.review_foo %>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! So `group_by(&:destination_id)` creates a hash with the destination ID as the key?

Comment: Exactly. Basically instead of going back to the database again and again with `find_by_destination_id` you are loading them all up front, then grabbing the right one from the hash.